# Adding dropdown values dynamically in inline datatable

Tags: jquery, dropdown, inline-editing

I am using inline editable datatable, I have a dropdown Markup like

```
 function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
            jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<select id="userrole" class="form-control input-sm"></select>';

        }
```

From Server side I am getting values as JSON.

```
success: function (data) {
           //alert("success");
         var userdata=JSON.parse(data);

          // alert(userdata);
         for(i=0;i<userdata.length;i++)
         {
             //alert(userdata[i].rolename)
             $('#userrole').append('<option value="'+userdata[i].roleid+'" selected="selected">'+userdata[i].roleid+'</option>');
         };
```

I need to append the values to selectbox, But, its not working,nothing reflects, i added my ajax script at the bottom of the inline js..Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the data like below:

```
success: function (data) {
           //alert("success");
         var userdata=JSON.parse(data);

          // alert(userdata);
         for(i=0;i<userdata.length;i++)
         {
            $('<option/>', {
              value: userdata[i].roleid,
              html: userdata[i].roleid
            }).appendTo('#userrole select');
         };
         $('#userrole select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: Its working thank you, is it possible to set default selected value?

Comment: Yes, to select first item use: $('#userrole select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");